# export user details from database via cron

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

Is there any way I can export user details from joomla database such as name, password, email address, and import them into owncloud database via a cronjob?

Comment: Have a look in the `ROOT/cli` directory where you will find a couple of scripts that you base base your own script on.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, I'll take a look but first i need to identify whether its possible, someone told me the owncloud and joomla encoding algorithm for password generation is different

Comment: I don't know about owncloud, so perhaps it may be easier for you to create a simple PHP file with 1 single variable `<?php $foo = 'bar'; ?>` and then try to push this value to the database.

Answer (score 1):

There might be others, more elegant ways to do it but I did it pretty simple - I created a non-Joomla PHP file, which connects to Joomla's DB and dumps user table into a CSV file. I then scheduled to open this page with CRON.

Notice the headers for pushing the file as a download are commented out, so the file will be created and saved in the same directory with your PHP file.

```
<?php

// Database Connection

$host="localhost";
$uname="dbuser";
$pass="dbP@$$";
$database = "joomla_db"; 

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or 
die("Database could not be selected"); 

$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

$output = "";
$table = "ab7cd_users"; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql = mysql_query("select id,name,username,email,block from $table");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= $heading."\t";
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -1);
$output .="\r\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .=$row["$i"]."\t";
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -1);
$output .="\r\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename = "users.csv";
/*
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
*/

file_put_contents ($filename , $output);

echo "Success";

exit;

?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, that looks like a good script, i have one similar, what would you suggest to upload the data into owncloud db? and do you know whether importing joomla! passwords will work in owncloud?

Comment: I am not familiar with owncloud but I doubt that it will work with Joomla password encryption algorithm.