# Need to dump specific table to excel

Tags: repeatable-field

I need to setup a j3 content page with one or more buttons that start a joomla table dump to an excel file on the user pc. The SQL Query shall be specific for each button.
Now I have not been able to succede with the dumping routine to Excel. Anybody has a possible solution or a piece of code?

Answer (score 3):

I recently answered a question regarding exporting the list of Joomla users to CSV - [export user details from database via cron](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17562/export-user-details-from-database-via-cron/17566#17566). The same code can be used for exporting data from any Joomla table. As far as invoking this PHP code from an article - look into Jumi extension - https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/jumi.